# why use "%.24s\r\n" instead of "%24s\r\n" in the calling of function snprintf

Tags: c++

```
char    buff[MAXLINE];
time_t  ticks;

ticks = time(NULL);
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks)); // with .
```

I have tried the following line and don't see any difference:

```
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));  // without .
```

Do I miss some key point here?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%.24s` specifies that a *maximum* of 24 characters be printed.

`%24s` specifies that a *minimum* of 24 characters be printed.

Comment: you beat me to it!  Here's the reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @ebyrob : That's _a_ reference, not _the_ reference. ;-] _The_ reference is ISO/IEC 9899 (the C language standard).

Comment: I didn't have the $250 to link a copy of that particular PDF file (or any idea which one to choose).  But ya, definitely should have been an a not a the.

Comment: @ebyrob : FWIW, it's $30 from ANSI. :-]